# How to make header manager as dynamic in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my case my header manager value needs to be changed according to the user logged in how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of users and corresponding header values in a CSV file - you can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) to read the values from file into JMeter Variables and use the variables in the HTTP Header Manager. Header names and values don't have to be dynamic, you can put [a variable or a function reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) there.

Also be aware of [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) when designing your Test Plan